# how to ignore path of URL with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

What is tried to accomplish without success is ignoring by .htaccess any path of a domain and just transfer it to the index page, for example
the url example.com/asb , the asb will be ignored and the page that will appear will be the main index page , (while the URL still be asb if possible)
how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest and recommended way to achieve this is by using [`FallbackResource`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource)

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

As per official doc:

> In earlier versions of httpd, this effect typically required `mod_rewrite`, and the use of the `-f` and `-d` tests for file and directory existence. This now requires only one line of configuration.
>   **Existing files, such as images, css files, and so on, will be served normally.**

Comment: Both of answers turned out to be nice , I liked more the simple one line solution :)

Comment: How can I set 2 fallbackresource condtions by the length of the url that is being accessed?

Comment: `FallbackResource` is only one and is unconditional. For more complex requirements better to use `mod_rewrite` rules.

Answer (score 1):

This probably is the easiest approach:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

If the above does *not* show any effect, then most likely one of these issues needs to get solved:

- rewriting module is not loaded into the apache http server
- rewriting module is not enabled
- rewriting is not permitted to the location you want it to get applied
- you have implemented your rewriting rule at the wrong place
- your http server is unable to read the rewriting rule
- you have a syntax error in your rule set

All of these need to be tackled separately. You should start by monitoring your http server's error log file. What does it say?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Only issue I exprience is when somebody access the domaoj without path thw index in htaccess is being ignored, how can I fix it?

Comment: I modified the answer accordingly.